# Communication Complexity and Prefix Codes

Tags: coding-theory, communication-complexity

I need an advice.

There is in section "V. CONCLUDING REMARKS" of the paper [1],

a term that only the autho's paper use: "PREFIX CODING COMMUNICATION".

I googled the expression and the only result is the same paper [1].

It's difficult for a beginner in communication complexity to understand what the author is talking about because he doesn'st explain how to use a prefix code for solving the set intersection problem. He only writes "assigning an appropriate prefix code to the messages...". His explanation is too vague. Thanks in advance who ever can advice me.

[1] "Communication Complexity and Data Compression"

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.306.7941&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide a full citation for that paper (authors and where published, in addition to the title), so that if the link dies, we can figure out which paper it is referring to?  Thanks.  Also, have you looked up prefix codes?  "Prefix coding communication" might simply mean "communication using a prefix code" -- have you considered that possible interpretation?  Does it make sense in context?  Caveat: "I'm a beginner; can you explain this research paper to me?" might not be well-received: it's possible people might prefer you to study the fundamentals first.

Comment: The author is not being vague. Rather, he assumes that you read the rest of the paper before reading the conclusions section. To wit, the proofs of Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 explain "how to use a prefix code for solving the set intersection problem".

Comment: to my knowledege Communication Complexity is corcerned about the least amount (lower bounds) of communication between Alice and Bob and not designing an algorithm that have a complexity of O(nlogn), for example. The author demonstrate, using prefix codes (this encoding is interpreted as compression, right?) and Kraft's inequality, how to close a gap between the upper and lower bound. But it's clear for me how to solve the set intersection. Do you now how to solve the set intersection problem using a prefix code, Mr Filmus?

Comment: It's all in the paper. Read the paper.

Answer (score 1):

The author describes an algorithm due to Ahlswede and Cai to solve the set intersection problem, and then describes his generalization to the number-in-hand setting with any number of players. I will only describe the two player setting.

Ahlswede and Cai consider an algorithm of the following form. Alice gets a set $X \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$, and Bob gets a set $Y \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then there are two rounds:

1. Alice sends Bob a description of $X$.
2. Bob sends Alice a description of $X \cap Y$.

It remains to determine the encoding of $X$ and $X \cap Y$. For the second round, things are simple: for each $x \in X$, Bob sends a bit describing whether $x \in Y$ or not, for a total of $|X|$ bits.

The first round is more complicated. One option is to always send the entire set $X$ in the same way, at the cost on $n$ bits. This algorithm uses $2n$ bits in the worst case, when $X = \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Another option is to use a more complicated encoding scheme. One thing which this scheme should accomplish is that after Alice finishes sending the message, Bob knows that it's his turn to speak. This only happens if the set of messages that Alice sends forms a prefix code.

Suppose that the length of the codeword that Alice sends when her input is $A$ is $\ell_A$. The communication complexity of the protocol is then $\max_A \ell_A + |A|$. On the other hand, Kraft's inequality states that a prefix code exists if and only if
$$
\sum_A 2^{-\ell_A} \leq 1.
$$
Now suppose we're aiming at a communication complexity of $L$ bits. Then we need to have $\ell_A \leq L - |A|$, and so
$$
1 \geq \sum_A 2^{-\ell_A} \geq \sum_A 2^{|A|-L} = 2^{-L} \sum_k \binom{n}{k} 2^k = 2^{-L} 3^n.
$$
This shows that $2^L \geq 3^n$ and so $L \geq (\log_2 3)n$. Conversely, if $L = \lceil (\log_2 3)n \rceil$ then such a code exists, and we get a communication protocol with this complexity.

It so happens that this complexity is optimal. Ahlwede and Cai prove that using the rank bound, which states that the communication complexity is at least the base-2 logarithm of the sum of the ranks of the matrices $M_z(x,y)$, given by $M_z(x,y) = 1$ if on inputs $x,y$ the output is $z$, and $M_z(x,y) = 0$ otherwise.

When $n=1$ the matrices are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and we get that the communication is at least $\log_2 3$. More generally, we have the identity
$$
M_z(x,y) = \bigotimes_{i=1}^n M_{z_i}(x_i,y_i),
$$
using tensor product notation, from which it easily follows that the rank of $M_z(x,y)$ equals $2^{|z|}$ (Hamming weight of $z$). The rank lower bound is then $\log_2 3^n = (\log_2 3) n$, matching the algorithm.

The exact communication complexity of set intersection is therefore $\lceil (\log_2 3) n \rceil$, and so the amortized communication complexity is $\log_2 3$. This is better than running the best protocol for $n=1$ in parallel, which would result in $2n$ bits. Ahlswede and Cai's protocol thus in some sense compresses the communication.

Recently, the advent of information complexity has resulted in a much improved understanding of amortized complexity, especially in the randomized case in which a small error is allowed. In that case, the amortized complexity exactly equals the information complexity. In fact, when a small error is allowed, [Braverman et al.](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2012/171/download/) show that the amortized complexity drops to 1.4923 bits. They also compute the amortized complexity of set disjointness to be 0.4827.

An outstanding open problem is finding a similar formula for the zero-error complexity of the direct product of a function – current techniques only work when a small error is allowed.

Comment: and what about Private Matching [1] for Set Intersection based on Balanced Allocations [3]? It's written [2]: "Their overhead for input lists of length k is O(k) communication and O(k ln ln k) computation, with small constant factors."The "O(k) communication with small constant" is OK,

But "O(k ln ln k)" is not. It seems Balanced Allocation is not very explored for the problem of set intersection outside the area of private computation. Probably Balanced Allocation is not well suited to be used with a Prefix Code Communication. Do you know anything about this, Mr. Filmus?

Comment: [1] also denoted as "private two-party computation of set intersection" in [2].

[2] Freedman, Michael J., Kobbi Nissim, and Benny Pinkas. "Efficient private matching and set intersection." Advances in Cryptology-EUROCRYPT 2004. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2004.

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24676-3_1

[3] Yossi Azar, Andrei Z. Broder, Anna R. Karlin, and Eli Upfal. Balanced allocations. SIAM Journal on Computing, 29(1):180–200, 1999.

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539795288490

Comment: @RicardoS. Unfortunately I cannot act as your research assistant.